# open the value of an input field in new tab. I would like to change the value of the input field in real time

Tags: javascript, html

I have a input field and a button.  the input field has a value at load time, but I would like to change that value after the page loads and on button click use the value as a url in a new tab.  I am new to javascript any input would be helpful.  Thanks in advance.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <input type="text" id="box" value="http://google.com" width="100%" />
</td>
    <td>
    <button id="newtab1" value = "Search" style="position: absolute;">New Tab</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If you show what code you've already tried, we can help you improve it.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an onclick property to your button.

```
<button id="newtab1" value = "Search" style="position: absolute;" onclick="MyFunction();">New Tab</button>
```

Then have your function process input

```
<script>
function MyFunction(){
    var url = document.getElementById('box').value
    window.open(url);
}   
</script>
```

Comment: Nothing is happening

Comment: I had to change console.log to window.open and it works... Thanks a bunch for your direction

Answer (score 0):

```
document.onload=function(){
var url ="your url "
document.getElementById("box").value=url;
}
function myFunction(){
Window.open(document.getElementById("box");
}
<button id="newtab1" value = "Search" style="position: absolute;" onclick="myFunction();">New Tab</button>
```